# Vanishing partial derivatives implies that map is constant

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $r>0$, and $a \in \mathbb R^n$. Suppose $f: B_r(a)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$ on $B_r(a)$ with $f_{x_j}(x)=0$ for every $j=1,\ldots, n$ and every $x \in B_r(a)$.

I want to show that $f(x)=f(a)$ for every $x \in B_r(a)$.

When $m=1$, I am able to prove this by using the mean value theorem for partial derivatives.

But I don't know how to generalize to $\mathbb R^m$. Can I use the fact that it holds for $m=1$? If so, how? If not, what argument would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f=(f_1,...,f_m)$. Thus each $f_j$ is real-valued !

You have shown that $f_j(x)=f_j(a)$ for every $x \in B_r(a)$ and $j=1,...,m$

It follws that  $f(x)=f(a)$ for every $x \in B_r(a)$.

Comment: Now I wonder why we have the hypothesis that $f$ is $C_1$. Do you happen to see where we might need continuity, for example?

Comment: The continuity of the partial derivatives is not needed.

Comment: And likewise for continuity of $f$ itself, right?